# JavaScript Regex To strip the html Tag with no attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an Html String like `<font>New</font><font face="Akronim---Regular" color="#00ff00">Text</font>`, With the use of JavaScript Regex i wanted to remove font tags with no attributes.

So the output of the above html string should be `New<font face="Akronim---Regular" color="#00ff00">Text</font>`

Below is the code, which helps me to strip all the font tags, But i am only require to strip font tags with no attribute.

```js
var replace = new RegExp('<'+'font'+'[^><]*>|<.'+'font'+'[^><]*>','g')

var text    = '<font>New</font><font face="Akronim---Regular" color="#00ff00">Text</font>';

console.log(text.replace(replace, ''))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to strip only the `font` tags or all the tags that do not have attributes?

Comment: Also what about nested tags: `<font>Hello <font face="Akronim---Regular">world</font></font>`?

Comment: This will probably be closed as duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/9867451

Comment: yes i want to strip all font tags with no attribute like color or face, even in nested it should be removed.

Comment: [Don't use a regex for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068)

Comment: Don't use Regex for this kind of stuffs. You would be better by creating a DOM element (you don't have to attach it) and stripping out the elements that you don't want.

Comment: if you're trying to do this from javascript, do you have access to the dom? if so, it would be way easier/cleaner/better to use `document.querySelectorAll('font:not([face])')` to get the elements you want and remove them from there

Comment: i don't have an access to the DOM, As I am running it on node server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it with a regex, you'll have to go tag by tag while keeping track of nesting levels so that you know when to remove a closing tag and when not.

To do so simply use an array that you constantly `push`/`pop` to/from it the type of the tag you encounter. When you encounter an opening tag, you `push` `true` if it has attributes and `false` if it doesn't, you then remove it if it doesn't have attributes. When you encounter a closing tag, you `pop` the type of the last encountered opening tag, if it had attributes (`true`), you skip to the next one, if it didn't have them (`false`) you remove it.

The regex should go over the opening and the closing tags in one run while giving us info about whether its a closing or an opening one and whether it has attributes or not. To do so we use regex like so `<\/?font [^\s]*?>`, we group `(\/)` and `([^\s]*?)` because whether or not those groups get matched, we will know if it is a closing tag or not and if it has attributes or not respectively (for example, if we match the `/` then it's a closing tag). We add in the `\s*` to handle empty spaces and the resulting regex is `/<(\/)?\s*font\s*([^\s]*?)\s*>/g`.

Here is the function that does the job:

```
function stripEmptyFonts(htmlString) {
   var tagTypes = [];

   return htmlString.replace(/<(\/)?\s*font\s*([^\s]*?)\s*>/g, function(match, closingSlash, attributes) {
      if(!closingSlash) {                                  // if it is an opening tag (no '/' was matched)
         tagTypes.push(!!attributes);                      // push true to the array tagTypes if it has attributes, otherwise push false (attributes will either be a string or null, we use the double negation !! to convert it to a boolean)
         return attributes ? match : "";                   // remove it if it has no attributes, otherwise keep it as is (read the docs of String#replace method)
      } else {                                             // if it is a closing tag (a '/' was matched)
         return tagTypes.pop() ? match : "";               // if the last tag we encounterd had attributes (pop returned true) we skip this closing tag, otherwise (pop return false) we remove it
      }
   });
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function stripEmptyFonts(htmlString) {
   var tagTypes = [];

   return htmlString.replace(/<(\/)?\s*font\s*([^\s]*?)\s*>/g, function(match, closingSlash, attributes) {
      if(!closingSlash) {
         tagTypes.push(!!attributes);
         return attributes ? match : "";
      } else {
         return tagTypes.pop() ? match : "";
      }
   });
}

var html = `
<font>New</font>
<font color="red">Hello <font>world</font>!</font>
<font>Hello <font color="blue">back</font>!</font>
<font>ABCD<font>EFGH<font color="black">IJKL<font>MNOP<font color="red">QRST</font>UVWX</font>YZ</font>1234</font>5678</font>`

console.log(stripEmptyFonts(html));
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this. Do not use RegEx to manipulate HTML

The container could be created in memory if needed

On Node you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

```js
document.querySelectorAll("font").forEach(f => {
  const parent = f.parentNode;
  if (f.attributes.length === 0) {
    if (f.innerHTML === "") { // remove empty fonts - we could do this before too
      parent.removeChild(f);
    } else {
      f.childNodes.forEach(child => parent.insertBefore(child.cloneNode(true), f));
      parent.removeChild(f);
    }
  }
});
console.log(document.getElementById("container").innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <font>Hello
    <font face="Akronim---Regular">world</font>
  </font>
  <font></font>
  <font>New</font>
  <font face="Akronim---Regular" color="#00ff00">Text</font>
</div>
```

Comment: Great Thanks!, but still i don't have an access to DOM, I am running it on node server, having html string as  `var text    = '<font>New</font><font face="Akronim---Regular" color="#00ff00">Text</font>';
`.

Comment: @Rahil then use something like [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

if you have no access of DOM element then you can try this answer

```
<script>
let htmlString = '<font>Hello </font><font>New <font face="Akronim-Regular">world</font></font>';
let expoString = htmlString.split('<font>');
expoString = expoString.filter(function(el) {
  return el != null && el != "";
});
for (let i = 0; i < expoString.length; i++) {
  let startTag = expoString[i].split('<font').length - 1;
  let endTag = expoString[i].split('</font>').length - 1;
  for (let j = 1; j <= endTag - startTag; j++) {
    expoString[i] = expoString[i].replace('</font>', '');
  }
}
console.log(expoString.join('')); // here you can return string instead
```